# How to use multiple selectors with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the code I was using (which works fine, until a client uploads a new image - then it has to be modified to work again:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

var firstProduct = $('.post-416 .woocommerce-loop-product__title').html();
 jQuery('.post-416 h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title').remove();
var firstPrice = $('.post-416 .price').html();
 jQuery('.post-416 .price').remove();
 console.log(firstProduct + firstPrice);
var secondProduct = $('.post-186 .woocommerce-loop-product__title').html();
 jQuery('.post-186 h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title').remove();
var secondPrice = $('.post-186 .price').html();
 $('.post-186 .price').remove();

var thirdProduct = $('.post-413 .woocommerce-loop-product__title').html();
$('.post-413 h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title').remove();
var thirdPrice = $('.post-413 .price').html();
 $('.post-413 .price').remove();

var fourthProduct = $('.post-218 .woocommerce-loop-product__title').html();
$('.post-218 h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title').remove();
var fourthPrice = $('.post-218 .price').html();
 $('.post-218 .price').remove();

var linebreak = ("<br>")

$( ".post-416 .et_overlay" ).append(firstProduct + linebreak + firstPrice);

$( ".post-186 .et_overlay" ).append(secondProduct + linebreak + secondPrice);

$( ".post-413 .et_overlay" ).append(thirdProduct + linebreak + thirdPrice);

$( ".post-218 .et_overlay" ).append(fourthProduct + linebreak + fourthPrice);

});
```

I'm attempting to replace it with something like this

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
var postClasses = jQuery("li[class*='post-").toArray();


jQuery( postClasses[0] ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + jQuery( this ).text() );
});


jQuery( ".et_overlay:first" ).appendTo();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is in the first section, i'm able to grab all `post-*` elements that also share the class `.woocommerce-loop-product__title`, when trying to do so in the second one i'm grabbing every bit of the content in post-* when I only want to grab the content for `post-*` and `.woocommerce-loop-product__title`.

How can I use multiple jQuery selectors (*particularly the Attribute Contains Selector*) in order to accomplish this? If this isn't the right solution then how should I approach this?

Comment: Are these woocommerce products ? (*do the `.post-*` elements also have the `product` class*?)

Comment: Yes , they are woocommerce products.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're meaning you don't want to have to add a line each time someone uploads, use a wildcard selector:

```
jQuery('[class^="post-"] .woocommerce-loop-product__title').html()
```

It will select all elements `.woocommerce-loop-product__title` that have a parent with a class name starting with `'post-'`. If `'post-'` isn't the first class name in those elements, use this instead:

```
jQuery('[class*="post-"] .woocommerce-loop-product__title').html()
```

Comment: So this is very close to what i'm doing, the issue here is that it only displays the first instance (there are 4 total) this is what i'm using -> jQuery('[class^=post] .woocommerce-loop-product__title').html();

Comment: What kind of element is `'post-*'`? Maybe use that element instead? Such as: `jQuery('div .woocommerce-loop-product__title').html()`. Or are you only trying to select a very specific 4 elements?

Comment: Trying to select specific elements, which change everytime an image is uploaded to WordPress (ie: post-416 might become post-89) and I need to select the post class, with the child class woocommerce-loop-product__title

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*if the post-* elements have the product class use it*/
  var posts = $('.product'), // or $('[class*="post-"])
    linebreak = '<br>';


  posts.each(function() {
    var self = $(this),
        title = self.find('.woocommerce-loop-product__title'),
        price = self.find('.price'),
        overlay = self.find('.et_overlay');

    overlay.append(title.html() + linebreak + price.html());

    title.remove();
    price.remove();
  });

});
```

Comment: Tried this, and it definitely is headed in the right direction! Thank you.